# _.mapObject is not supported in meteor

Tags: underscore.js

`_.mapObject` is not supported in meteor. How to use `_.mixin` to work `_.mapObject`. Please refer to my code below

```
var result = _.mapObject(typesOverall, function(val, key) {
    return  _.reduce(val, function(memo, v) {
        return memo + v.val;
    }, 0) / val.length * 10;
})
```

Comment: mapObject was introduced in [underscore 1.8](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog). Meteor uses underscore version 1.5.1 ([with a few patches applied](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commits/devel/packages/underscore/underscore.js)).

Comment: An alternative solution that doesn't use `mapObject` is possible. To come up with something it would help if you added a snippet showing what a valid `typesOverall` looks like (the `typesOverall` in your previous question isn't a valid object).