# Underscore group and sort nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

Using meteor, I've got a mongo aggregation returning a reactive var like so:

```
[{
"_id": "game1",
"playerpicks": [
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "atsa"
  },
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "suh"
  },
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "atsh"
  },
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "sua"
  }]  },{
"_id": "game2",
"playerpicks": [
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "atsa"
  },
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "suh"
  },
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "atsh"
  },
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "sua"
  }]  },  ....  ]
```

I need to convert this data into a grid that ideally looks like so:

```
GAME       al          Chris
game1    suh/atsh      sua/atsa
game2    sua/atsa      suh/atsh
```

Assuming this is too significant of a challenge I can make something like this work:

```
game 1    al: suh/atsh     Chris:  sua/atsa
game 2    al: sua/atsa     Chris:  suh/atsh
```

I am seeing the Mongo requires sorting to occur client-side so I'm focusing on using underscore, but can not get any result even in the initial step of either _.sortBy or _.groupBy on the nested array "playerpicks"

I've attempted as follows:

```
_.each(monArr, function(obj){ _.each(obj.playerpicks, function(nst){ _.groupBy( nst.player ) }) })
```

as well as:

```
_.groupBy(monArr, function(obj){return obj.playerpicks.player})
```

but I'm just way off.  no data returned.  any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a myriad of underscore functions, broken down into discrete chunks to hopefully make it a bit more readable:

```
// helper function to combine a player's picks into a string delimited by '/'
let combinePicks = player => _.pluck(player, 'pick').join('/');

// helper function to group a game by a player
let groupGame = game => _.chain(game.playerpicks)
    .groupBy('player')
    .mapObject(combinePicks)
    .value();

// map the data to create the object in the required form
let result = _.map(data, game => _.extend({GAME: game._id}, groupGame(game) ));
```

For earlier versions of underscore that don't support `mapObject` (pre 1.8) the same result can be achieved using reduce:

```
let combinePicks = function(memo, player, key){
    memo[key] = _.pluck(player, 'pick').join('/');
    return memo;
} 

let groupGame = game => _.chain(game.playerpicks)
    .groupBy('player')
    .reduce(combinePicks, {})
    .value();
```

```js
  var data = [{
"_id": "game1",
"playerpicks": [
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "atsa"
  },
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "suh"
  },
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "atsh"
  },
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "sua"
  }]  },{
"_id": "game2",
"playerpicks": [
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "atsa"
  },
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "suh"
  },
  {
    "player": "Chris",
    "pick": "atsh"
  },
  {
    "player": "al",
    "pick": "sua"
  }]  }
 ];

 let combinePicks = player => _.pluck(player, 'pick').join('/');

 let groupGame = game => _.chain(game.playerpicks)
  .groupBy('player')
  .mapObject(combinePicks)
  .value();
 
 let result = _.map(data, game => _.extend({GAME: game._id}, groupGame(game) ));


document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you GB, this is really complex (for me) but incredibly elegant and thought provoking and I'm working through it.  I've accepted the answer as it's clearly working in the code snippet, although in my app I'm getting a _.chain(...)... is not a function type error.  It seems to be related to the combinePicks function, though not 100% sure yet (chaining is very new to me as well as some other aspects you've taught me here).  So thank you again - I will update with my progress

Comment: GB, looks like I've got the same issue you id'd here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153000/mapobject-is-not-supported-in-meteor      Meteor doesn't support mapObject

Comment: I've added a few tweaks so that it works without using `mapObject`.

Comment: works like a charm G!  i clearly have a LOT to learn about working with/modifying arrays...  thank you very much!